# Export average value of one variable over 2 other variables

Tags: stata

I can use `tabout var1 var2...style(csv)` to export a matrix-like object with `var1` on one axis, `var2` on the other, and the frequencies that each combination of the values `var1` and `var2` occur. Is it possible to use `tabout` or some other commmand (preferably native to Stata) to do something similar except instead of the frequencies filling the cells, the average value of a third variable would. For example, suppose the skeleton of this structure is as follows:

```
    A    B    C    D
1
2
3
```

`var2` takes on values of `1, 2, 3` and `var1` takes on values `A, B, C, D`. Suppose that there is a third variable, `var3` that is continuous. Suppose the average value of `var3` when `var1==A` and `var2==1` is `3.1`. Then this cell would get filled in:

```
    A    B    C    D
1  3.1
2
3
```

The other values would similarly be filled in. Is there any way to do this in Stata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `table`'s `contents()` option:

```
clear
set more off

sysuse auto

table foreign rep78, contents(mean price)
```

Something similar can be achieved with `tabout` (from SSC):

```
tabout foreign rep78 using testtab.csv, sum cells(mean price) ptotal(none)
```

Comment: Also, check out `tabdisp`.